# Make one-to-many polymorphic relation with Entity Framework image table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am building am e-commerce API and I have a problem about how I can make one-to-many polymorphic relationship  with Entity Framework.

I have an `Image` entity like this:

```
using ecommerce.Domain.Base.Interfaces;
using ecommerce.Domain.Enum;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using tables.Base.Entity;

namespace ecommerce.Domain.Entities;

public class Image:BaseEntity
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public string ResizedUrl { get; set; }

    public EntitiesHasImages Type { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my typenum:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ecommerce.Domain.Enum;

public enum EntitiesHasImages
{
    Banner,
    Brand,
    Category,
    Product,
    Slider
}
```

I have a `Product` entity that has many images, like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using tables.Base.Entity;

namespace ecommerce.Domain.Entities;

public class Product: BaseEntity
{
    public Product()
    {
        Properties = new HashSet<Property>();
        Images = new HashSet<Image>();
        Reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string MetaLogo { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }  

    public float Price { get; set; }    
    public int Quantity  { get; set; }
    public int MinQuantity { get; set; }
    public int SellingNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand? Brand { get; set; }

    public virtual Coupon? Coupon { get; set; }   

    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `Category` entity that also might have many images like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using tables.Base.Entity;

namespace ecommerce.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        public Category()
        {
            Child = new HashSet<Category>();
            Products= new HashSet<Product>();
            Images = new HashSet<Image>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Category? Parent { get;set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Child { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public string ? Meta_Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I define this relationship? Please help me